# Cant compile Windows Socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, c++11, compiler-errors

i've made in my windows desktop, a c socket code, but when i compile, it gives me erros, i dnt know how to proceed, can someone help me? i am working in windows 7, but also tried this same code in windows 10, but i got the same errors, here is the c code, i also tried in c++ but got the same errors, c code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define PORT 5555
#define HOST "192.168.1.30"
#define MAX_L 4096
int main(void){
    char bfs[MAX_L], bfr[MAX_L];
    int sockfd;
    socklen_t sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    struct sockaddr_in target_addr;
    struct WSAData wsa;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa);

    sockfd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    target_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    target_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    target_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(HOST);

    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&target_addr, sin_size);

    while(1){

        gets(bfs);
        send(sockfd, &bfs, MAX_L, 0);
        recv(sockfd, &bfr, MAX_L, 0);
        printf("%s\n", bfr);


    }

    closesocket((SOCKET) sockfd);

    WSACleanup();


}
```

error:

> gcc -o csocketcode csocketcode.c -lwinsock2

Comment: You should probably include the error message as well.

Comment: You probably need `#include <windows.h>` **after** `#include <winsock2.h>`

Comment: regarding: `gets(bfs);`   the `gets()` function has been depreciated for years and completely removed from the latest versions of the C language.  If you had enabled the warnings, then your compiler would have told you this.  Suggest using `fgets()`  (be sure to read the MAN page for `fgets()`

Comment: C++ and C are two different languages, pick one and remove the tag for the other

Comment: when calling: `recv()`, `send()`, `connect()`, `socket()`, and other C library functions, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  (read the MAN pages for those functions to know what to check for.

Comment: strongly suggest only using the C library functions and not the windows specialty functions

Answer (score 2):

When calling `send()` and `recv()`, DON'T use the `&` operator to pass your `char[]` arrays.  Arrays *decay* into pointers, so pass the arrays as-is. `send()` expects a `const char*`, and `recv()` expects a `char*`, but you are passing them both a `char(*)[4096]` instead, which is not what the functions want. Let the arrays decay to `char*` for you.

There are other problems with your code:

- missing `#include <windows.h>`
- `sockfd` is declared as `int` when it should be `SOCKET` instead.
- [`gets()` is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/). Also, you are (potentially) sending more data than `gets()` actually returns.
- your use of `printf()` is expecting null-terminated data, but `recv()` does not guarantee a null terminator.
- no error handling at all.

Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define PORT 5555
#define HOST "192.168.1.30"
#define MAX_L 4096

int main(void) {
    char bfs[MAX_L], bfr[MAX_L];
    SOCKET sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in target_addr;
    struct WSAData wsa;
    int err, num_recvd;
    size_t str_len;

    err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsa);
    if (err != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup() failed, error %d\n", err);
        return -1;
    }

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        err = WSAGetLastError();
        fprintf(stderr, "socket() failed, error %d\n", err);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    target_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    target_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    target_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(HOST);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&target_addr, sizeof(target_addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        err = WSAGetLastError();
        fprintf(stderr, "connect() failed, error %d\n", err);
        closesocket(sockfd);
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    while (fgets(bfs, MAX_L, stdin)) {
        str_len = strlen(bfs);
        if ((str_len > 0) && (bfs[str_len-1] == '\n')) {
            --str_len;
        }

        if (send(sockfd, bfs, str_len, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            err = WSAGetLastError();
            fprintf(stderr, "send() failed, error %d\n", err);
            closesocket(sockfd);
            WSACleanup();
            return -1;
        }

        num_recvd = recv(sockfd, bfr, MAX_L, 0);
        if (num_recvd == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            err = WSAGetLastError();
            fprintf(stderr, "recv() failed, error %d\n", err);
            closesocket(sockfd);
            WSACleanup();
            return -1;
        }

        if (num_recvd == 0) {
            break;
        }

        printf("%.*s\n", num_recvd, bfr);
    }

    closesocket(sockfd);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code under gcc compiles but cannot be linked because `gcc` doesn't recognize

`#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")`

Add `-Werror=unknown-pragmas` as compiler flag and you will see `error: ignoring pragma comment` as compiler message.

So you need to pass `Ws2_32` library to link in command line:

```
gcc -o csocketcode csocketcode.c -lWs2_32
```

`gcc` tells you about incompatible pointers type (it is treated as warnings), what is described in Chipster's answer. Fix it.